# Codemirror simplemode plugin create regex for function

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I'm trying to define the syntax highlighting regular expression for a function definition for CodeMirror using the simple mode plugin. I found this example in the [docs](https://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html):

```
  {
   regex: /(function)(\s+)([a-z$][\w$]*)/,
   token: ["keyword", null, "variable-2"]
  }
```

which works fine for the syntax below

[image]

but in my case, I am looking for an expression that would manage to format `foobar(arg1, arg2, ...)` (without `function`). Simply rewriting the definition to

```
  {
   regex: /(\s+)([a-z$][\w$]*)/,
   token: [null, "variable-2"]
  }
```

does not seem to work and produces this syntax highlighting:

[image]

How can I obtain the syntax highlighting without the "function" keyword?

**Update**

As per @Wiktor Stribiżew's comment I tried:

```
{
  regex: /(\w+\s*\(|\G(?!^)\s*,)\s*([a-z$][\w$]*)/,
  token: ["variable-2", null]
}
```

I had to swap the token elements as otherwise the function name wouldn't have been coloured. The question is now, how do I get the first argument (of the function which is what I am trying to parse) to be ignored, so it will be coloured by one of the subsequent rules? In the example below, `var1` should be coloured just like other standard variables such as `xyz` and `abc`.

[image]

Comment: Try `(\w+\s*\(|\G(?!^)\s*,)\s*([a-z$][\w$]*)` keeping  `token: [null, "variable-2"]`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew: I'm getting closer (please see the update). Minor problem is that the immediate first token within the brackets is not matched by any other rule.

Comment: And the other thing I noticed is that the first bracket `(` gets also colourised which is not intended...

Comment: Ok, I found out what's wrong: the `null` element. It seems like it's assigning a token type (of type "null). If set to undefined (or left out), it works fine. I settled with `{regex: /([_\w]*) *(\()/, token: ['variable-2']}` which seems to assign `variable-2` to the first group (and nothing to the 2nd group which is the opening bracket). At least that's my take on these observations (without having delved into the source code of this plugin)...

Comment: Note that `[_\w]` = `\w`